# testng factory, group by instances and dependencies

Tags: testng

I had a test class with some group dependencies that I defined in the xml suite using the depends tags (I think this is more flexible and easier to change that way).
Then I needed that test to be expanded to test many examples. I added another test class with a factory, creating many instances of the first test class with different values.
All instances were running until the first failure... a fail of one instance caused the other instances to be skipped.
After re-reading the testng docs, I understood that this is the expected behavior of a factory (why?) and group-by-instances = true configuration is required in order to run it as I expect.
I added the tag, but now it will run only the first group in my dependency schema...
Were is my mistake?

Comment: What language / platform / framework are you working with?

Comment: Java (is testng available with other languages? ) on Windows. I'm using eclipse with testng plugin. 6.8.6 version.

Comment: whitout code is hard to understand about what are you talking and where is issue.